# uncaughtException: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "expectedInvestmentSupportInfo"

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, nestjs, dto

I have created a DTO called `UploadedInvestmentDocumentInput` and have attached it to the `expectedInvestmentSupportInfo` property but I am getting the following error:-

```
uncaughtException: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "expectedInvestmentSupportInfo".

 Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "expectedInvestmentSupportInfo". 
Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
```

**opportunity-account.input.ts**

```js
import { UploadedDocumentInput } from '@app/dto/common.input';
import {
  Field,
  InputType, OmitType, PickType, registerEnumType,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsEnum, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

import {
  ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType,
  SourceOfFundsType,
} from '@/generated-cbms-api-client';

import { OpportunityAccount } from './opportunity-account.response';

registerEnumType(SourceOfFundsType, { name: 'SourceOfFundsType' });
registerEnumType(ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType, { name: 'ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType' });

@InputType()
export class UploadedInvestmentDocumentInput extends OmitType(UploadedDocumentInput, ['documentType'], InputType) {
  @IsEnum(ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType)
  @Field(() => ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType)
  documentType: ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType;
}

@InputType()
export class UpsertAnticipatedInvestmentActivitiesInput extends PickType(
  OpportunityAccount,
  [
    'isPlanningInvestIn12Months',
    'anticipatedInvestmentOpportunitiesCountRange',
    'investmentDescription',
  ],
  InputType,
) {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => UploadedInvestmentDocumentInput)
  @Field(() => [UploadedInvestmentDocumentInput], { description: 'Expected investment support info' })
  expectedInvestmentSupportInfo: UploadedInvestmentDocumentInput[];
}
```

UploadedDocumentInput ( common DTO )

```js
import { Field, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { FileUpload, GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

@InputType()
export class UploadedDocumentInput {
  @Field(() => Number)
  documentType: number;

  @Field(() => GraphQLUpload)
  frontSideDoc: FileUpload;

  @Field(() => GraphQLUpload, { nullable: true })
  backSideDoc?: FileUpload;
}
```

**opportunity-account.output.ts**

```
class UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse extends OmitType(UploadedDocumentResponse, ['documentType'], InputType) {
  @IsEnum(ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType)
  @Field(() => ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType)
  documentType: ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType;
}

@ObjectType()
export class OpportunityAccount extends AccountsCommonDetails {
  @IsMongoId()
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Customer id' })
  customerId: string;

// I believe issue is here ( when I commented out the field below, this error vanished !)

  @IsEnum(UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse)
  @Field(() => [UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse], { description: 'Expected investment support info' })
  expectedInvestmentSupportInfo: UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse[];

 

}
```

What decorator or property am I missing due to which I am getting the above mentioned error ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `ObjectType` decorator to `UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse` and remove `InputType`  from `OmitType(UploadedDocumentResponse, ['documentType'])`, since I am creating an object that gets bind to a response field, not an input field !

**opportunity-account.output.ts**

```js
@ObjectType()
class UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse extends OmitType(UploadedDocumentResponse, ['documentType']) {
  @IsEnum(ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType)
  @Field(() => ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType)
  documentType: ExpectedInvestmentSupportInfoType;
}

@ObjectType()
export class OpportunityAccount extends AccountsCommonDetails {
  @IsMongoId()
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Customer id' })
  customerId: string;

// I believe issue is here ( when I commented out the field below, this error vanished !)

  @IsEnum(UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse)
  @Field(() => [UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse], { description: 'Expected investment support info' })
  expectedInvestmentSupportInfo: UploadedInvestmentDocumentResponse[];

 

}
```